# NullPointerException while subscribing to a topic on MqttAndroidClient

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, mqtt

I have used Android Service jar from Paho Eclipse repo. I am hitting NUllPOinterException while subscribing to any topic after client connection.

```
    public void connect(View view) {

    MqttConnectOptions conOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();

    String uri = "tcp://" + host + ":" + port;
    boolean cleanSession = true;
    // int timeout = 60 ;
    // int keepalive = 60 ;
    clientHandle = uri + clientId;

    MqttAndroidClient client;
    client = Connections.getInstance(this)
            .createClient(this, uri, clientId);

    Connection conn = new Connection(clientHandle, clientId, host, port,
            this, client, sslConnection);

    conOpt.setCleanSession(cleanSession);
    // conOpt.setConnectionTimeout(timeout);
    conOpt.setKeepAliveInterval(100);;

    MqttCallbackHandler callback = new MqttCallbackHandler(this,
            MainActivity.this, clientHandle);

    conn.addConnectionOptions(conOpt);
    Connections.getInstance(this).addConnection(conn);
    String[] topics = { "hello", "hi" };
    int qos = 0;
    try {
        IMqttToken t = client.connect(conOpt, null, new ActionListener(this,
                Action.CONNECT, uri, (String[]) null));
        //t.waitForCompletion(90);
        client.setCallback(callback);
        IMqttToken token = Connections
                .getInstance(this)
                .getConnection(clientHandle)
                .getClient()
                .subscribe(
                        "shatinTopic",
                        qos,
                        null,
                        new ActionListener(this, Action.SUBSCRIBE, uri,
                                topics));
        Log.d("SUBSCRIBE", token.getResponse().toString());
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.getCause();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.getCause();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getCause();
    }
}
```

Errors :

```
11-09 15:17:24.702: E/AndroidRuntime(26671): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 15:17:24.702: E/AndroidRuntime(26671): at      org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.subscribe(MqttAndroidClient.java:788)
```

Can someone please help where exactly things are going wrong.

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got this answer from paho dev mailing list.

> Because connect is asynchronous, and the connection may not established the time you call subscribe.
>   you should either waitForCompletion  or  call subscribe in IMqttActionListener.onSuccess,  if you   are using IMqttToken connect(MqttConnectOptions options, Object userContext, IMqttActionListener callback)

Although waitForCompletion gave server time out error, subscribing on onSuccess method of listener solved the issue.